# Estimate term in Ramanujan Lost Notebook (classic analytic number theory)

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

This is the [fault of Igor Rivin](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136940/sum-of-powers-of-divisors-function), who asked about sums of divisor functions. I will put in links eventually. What I would like to know is the size of the right hand side in Ramanujan's formula (381), see original and a rendition [FROM HERE](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.6944) in the second jpeg below. The quotes from Ramanujan are in (including some sign corrections) Nicolas and Robin, The Ramanujan Journal, Volume 1, Issue 2, June 1997, pages 119-153, *Highly Composite Numbers by Srinivasa Ramanujan*.

The questions are about the surprising size of the thing. For $s = 1/2$, formula 380, as a function of $N$ it is still larger than any power of $\log N$. Note that the construction "generalised superior highly composite numbers" always gives something smaller than any root $N^\alpha$ for $\alpha > 0$.

Question (A): is there a subinterval of the given $1/2 < s < 1$ for which the right-hand side of (381) has comparable growth to some $(\log N)^\beta$ for some $0 < \beta < \infty$?

Question (B): how do we get down to the really tiny growth for $s=1$, dominant term $\log \log N? $ Note that this was later improved in [Robin's Criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossally_abundant_number#Relation_to_the_Riemann_hypothesis).

Between (330) and (332) we find
$$ S_s(x) = - s \sum \;  \frac{x^{\rho - s}}{\rho (\rho - s)}  $$
where the sum is ``over the complex roots of $\zeta.$''

With that in mind, the right hand side of (381) is
$$  | \zeta(s) | \exp \left\{ \mbox{Li}  \left( (\log N)^{1-s} \right)   - \frac{2s(2^{1/(2s)} -1)}{2s-1} \frac{(\log N)^{\frac{1}{2}-s}}{\log \log N}  \right\} 
+ \frac{S_s(\log N)}{\log \log N} + O \left\{ \frac{(\log N)^{\frac{1}{2}-s}}{(\log \log N)^2}  \right\} $$

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/71453/what-should-be-learned-in-an-introductory-analytic-number-theory-course?rq=1

Comment: It may be a good idea to also write the relevant formulas in the body of the question.

Comment: @RicardoAndrade working on it

Comment: @RicardoAndrade, got it. There are notes by Nicolas and Robin emphasizing the function (parenthesis) order in the use of the logarithmic integral function.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT, Monday: while specific constants depend on RH, the following is unconditional: for $s=1$ the "ratio" grows as $\log \log n,$ but for fixed $0 < s < 1$ the "ratio" grows faster than any power of $\log n.$

I heard from Jean-Louis Nicolas. For fixed $\frac{1}{2} < s < 1$ and $n \rightarrow \infty$ the growth of Ramanujan's "generalised superior highly composite numbers" is still swifter than any power of $\log n.$ My own fiddling with formula (381) shows that the single dominant term is an awfully good estimate. Note that $\zeta(3/4) \approx -3.441285$

```
==================================

   t  0.75

  ratio = sigma_{3/4}(n) / n^{3/4}

  Ram = exp( Li ( (log n)^{1/4} )  ) 

==================================

 ratio   1.594603558                                                         2 bump   2^1
 ratio   2.294142325                                  log n   1.791759469    6 bump   3^1
 ratio   2.802796526                                  log n   2.48490665     12 bump   2^2
 ratio   3.641028199                                  log n   4.094344562    60 bump   5^1
 ratio   4.033928726                                  log n   4.787491743    120 bump   2^3
 ratio   4.573537136                                  log n   5.886104031    360 bump   3^2
 ratio   5.63628118                                   log n   7.832014181    2520 bump   7^1
 ratio   5.962699514                                  log n   8.525161361    5040 bump   2^4
 ratio   6.949884201                                  log n   10.92305663    55440 bump   11^1
 ratio   7.965010441                                  log n   13.48800599    720720 bump   13^1
 ratio   8.224276385                                  log n   14.18115317    1441440 bump   2^5
 ratio   8.649956395                                  log n   15.27976546    4324320 bump   3^3
 ratio   9.245517654    over  Ram   3.028600308       log n   16.88920337    21621600 bump   5^2
 ratio   10.34983665    over  Ram   3.165867659       log n   19.72241672    367567200 bump   17^1
 ratio   11.48711898    over  Ram   3.083261736       log n   22.6668557     6983776800 bump   19^1
 ratio   12.58086187    over  Ram   3.172163117       log n   25.80234991    160626866400 bump   23^1
 ratio   12.81668461    over  Ram   3.231623923       log n   26.49549709    321253732800 bump   2^6
 ratio   13.84228269    over  Ram   3.095238829       log n   29.86279292     bump   29^1
 ratio   14.4487679    over  Ram   3.230853497       log n   31.80870307     bump   7^2
 ratio   15.54855733    over  Ram   3.101387246       log n   35.24269028     bump   31^1
 ratio   15.88423195    over  Ram   3.168342458       log n   36.34130256     bump   3^4
 ratio   16.94303437    over  Ram   3.19811678       log n   39.95222048     bump   37^1
 ratio   17.9887252    over  Ram   3.217053505       log n   43.66579254     bump   41^1
 ratio   18.18553099    over  Ram   3.084784213       log n   44.35893972     bump   2^7
 ratio   19.26852148    over  Ram   3.103456721       log n   48.12013984     bump   43^1
 ratio   20.34195462    over  Ram   3.114010326       log n   51.97028744     bump   47^1
 ratio   21.37753969    over  Ram   3.113314008       log n   55.94057936     bump   53^1
 ratio   21.78937675    over  Ram   3.173291822       log n   57.55001727     bump   5^3
 ratio   22.81291905    over  Ram   3.163514705       log n   61.62755471     bump   59^1
 ratio   23.85808075    over  Ram   3.152929072       log n   65.73842858     bump   61^1
 ratio   24.87685838    over  Ram   3.135532889       log n   69.9431212     bump   67^1
 ratio   25.46187993    over  Ram   3.209270267       log n   72.34101647     bump   11^2
 ratio   26.50287028    over  Ram   3.188425241       log n   76.60369635     bump   71^1
 ratio   26.67341265    over  Ram   3.208942324       log n   77.29684353     bump   2^8
 ratio   27.74144999    over  Ram   3.187825713       log n   81.58730297     bump   73^1
 ratio   28.78835877    over  Ram   3.162018062       log n   85.95675082     bump   79^1
 ratio   29.05524627    over  Ram   3.191332103       log n   87.05536311     bump   3^5
 ratio   30.11185937    over  Ram   3.163394697       log n   91.47420372     bump   83^1
 ratio   31.15104963    over  Ram   3.132063376       log n   95.96284009     bump   89^1
 ratio   31.73094398    over  Ram   3.190368501       log n   98.52778944     bump   13^2
 ratio   32.75755091    over  Ram   3.154083607       log n   103.1025004     bump   97^1
 ratio   33.78573385    over  Ram   3.253082917       log n   107.7176209     bump   101^1
 ratio   34.83070774    over  Ram   3.213503967       log n   112.3523499     bump   103^1
 ratio   35.87765418    over  Ram   3.173480786       log n   117.0251788     bump   107^1
 ratio   36.94119501    over  Ram   3.267554004       log n   121.7165266     bump   109^1
 ratio   38.00705978    over  Ram   3.224796113       log n   126.4439145     bump   113^1
 ratio   38.15155234    over  Ram   3.237055915       log n   127.1370616     bump   2^9
 ratio   39.16001407    over  Ram   3.188810947       log n   131.9812487     bump   127^1
 ratio   40.17133587    over  Ram   3.271163165       log n   136.8564461     bump   131^1
 ratio   41.1745089    over  Ram   3.21940471       log n   141.776427     bump   137^1
 ratio   41.57610945    over  Ram   3.250805563       log n   143.7223371     bump   7^3
 ratio   42.60313855    over  Ram   3.200038518       log n   148.6568111     bump   139^1
 ratio   43.60210727    over  Ram   3.275073797       log n   153.6607574     bump   149^1
 ratio   44.61432694    over  Ram   3.22071367       log n   158.6780372     bump   151^1
 ratio   45.18291626    over  Ram   3.261760202       log n   161.5112505     bump   17^2
 ratio   46.20162379    over  Ram   3.206931917       log n   166.5674964     bump   157^1
 ratio   47.21440711    over  Ram   3.277230899       log n   171.6612466     bump   163^1
 ratio   48.23074282    over  Ram   3.220290278       log n   176.7792404     bump   167^1
 ratio   49.24183179    over  Ram   3.287799086       log n   181.932532     bump   173^1
 ratio   50.24805522    over  Ram   3.228541517       log n   187.1199178     bump   179^1
 ratio   51.26631908    over  Ram   3.293967076       log n   192.3184148     bump   181^1
 ratio   51.82404921    over  Ram   3.205575163       log n   195.2628538     bump   19^2
 ratio   52.83273596    over  Ram   3.267967455       log n   200.5151272     bump   191^1
 ratio   53.04563115    over  Ram   3.281136081       log n   201.6137395     bump   3^6
 ratio   54.07005962    over  Ram   3.220955494       log n   206.8764297     bump   193^1
 ratio   55.09832965    over  Ram   3.282209579       log n   212.1596334     bump   197^1
 ratio   56.13824653    over  Ram   3.22181287       log n   217.4529382     bump   199^1
 ratio   56.45557713    over  Ram   3.240024693       log n   219.0623761     bump   5^4
 ratio   57.47533017    over  Ram   3.298549027       log n   224.4142343     bump   211^1
 ratio   57.60476235    over  Ram   3.305977229       log n   225.1073815     bump   2^10
 ratio   58.60299034    over  Ram   3.241380692       log n   230.5145532     bump   223^1
 ratio   59.6050657    over  Ram   3.296806323       log n   235.9395033     bump   227^1
 ratio   60.61759257    over  Ram   3.232422062       log n   241.3732253     bump   229^1
 ratio   61.63403256    over  Ram   3.286623539       log n   246.8242637     bump   233^1
 ratio   62.64799568    over  Ram   3.221820568       log n   252.3007273     bump   239^1
 ratio   63.67221839    over  Ram   3.27449363       log n   257.7855242     bump   241^1
 ratio   64.68192381    over  Ram   3.209099212       log n   263.3109771     bump   251^1
 ratio   65.68962805    over  Ram   3.259094987       log n   268.8600532     bump   257^1
 ratio   66.69547057    over  Ram   3.308998395       log n   274.4322072     bump   263^1
 ratio   67.69958251    over  Ram   3.241375141       log n   280.0269186     bump   269^1
 ratio   68.71316482    over  Ram   3.289904251       log n   285.6290375     bump   271^1
 ratio   69.28195086    over  Ram   3.317137047       log n   288.7645317     bump   23^2
 ratio   70.30232697    over  Ram   3.24929488       log n   294.3885492     bump   277^1
 ratio   71.32665713    over  Ram   3.296638274       log n   300.0269038     bump   281^1
 ratio   72.36039885    over  Ram   3.229428647       log n   305.6723507     bump   283^1
 ratio   73.382162    over  Ram   3.275029711       log n   311.3525233     bump   293^1
 ratio   74.38270722    over  Ram   3.319683824       log n   317.0793711     bump   307^1
 ratio   75.38709562    over  Ram   3.249769843       log n   322.819164     bump   311^1
 ratio   76.400164    over  Ram   3.293440965       log n   328.5653672     bump   313^1
 ratio   77.41711457    over  Ram   3.224374375       log n   334.324269     bump   317^1
 ratio   78.41473649    over  Ram   3.265924703       log n   340.1263873     bump   331^1
 ratio   79.41169082    over  Ram   3.307447227       log n   345.9464703     bump   337^1
 ratio   80.39941875    over  Ram   3.236182228       log n   351.7957951     bump   347^1
 ratio   81.39513097    over  Ram   3.276260954       log n   357.650867     bump   349^1
 ratio   82.39459553    over  Ram   3.316490715       log n   363.517335     bump   353^1
 ratio   83.39362406    over  Ram   3.244889968       log n   369.4006574     bump   359^1
 ratio   84.38818935    over  Ram   3.283589029       log n   375.3060193     bump   367^1
 ratio   85.38244953    over  Ram   3.322276218       log n   381.2275977     bump   373^1
 ratio   86.37645598    over  Ram   3.24984013       log n   387.1651339     bump   379^1
 ratio   87.37414754    over  Ram   3.28737742       log n   393.1131689     bump   383^1
 ratio   87.49088072    over  Ram   3.291769406       log n   393.8063161     bump   2^11
 ratio   88.48973144    over  Ram   3.329350308       log n   399.7698954     bump   389^1
 ratio   89.48467856    over  Ram   3.256298948       log n   405.7538317     bump   397^1
 ratio   90.48327589    over  Ram   3.292637363       log n   411.7477931     bump   401^1
 ratio   91.47816766    over  Ram   3.328840935       log n   417.7615083     bump   409^1
 ratio   92.46594017    over  Ram   3.255165011       log n   423.7993792     bump   419^1
 ratio   93.46081907    over  Ram   3.290188663       log n   429.842012     bump   421^1
 ratio   94.01493491    over  Ram   3.309695722       log n   433.2093079     bump   29^2
 ratio   95.00882623    over  Ram   3.23649366       log n   439.2754159     bump   431^1
 ratio   96.00974315    over  Ram   3.270590084       log n   445.3461537     bump   433^1
 ratio   97.01081885    over  Ram   3.304691917       log n   451.4306531     bump   439^1
 ratio   98.01547483    over  Ram   3.338915714       log n   457.5242229     bump   443^1
 ratio   99.02034486    over  Ram   3.264797057       log n   463.6312457     bump   449^1
 ratio   100.0221593    over  Ram   3.297827853       log n   469.7559291     bump   457^1
 ratio   101.0275168    over  Ram   3.330975468       log n   475.8893272     bump   461^1
 ratio   102.0396879    over  Ram   3.257021972       log n   482.0270542     bump   463^1
 ratio   103.0554254    over  Ram   3.289443466       log n   488.1733835     bump   467^1
 ratio   103.2368708    over  Ram   3.295235055       log n   489.2719958     bump   3^7
 ratio   103.6295806    over  Ram   3.307770024       log n   491.6698911     bump   11^3
 ratio   104.6417008    over  Ram   3.34007606       log n   497.8415917     bump   479^1
 ratio   105.2050828    over  Ram   3.251655773       log n   501.2755789     bump   31^2
 ratio   106.2199051    over  Ram   3.283021679       log n   507.463843     bump   487^1
 ratio   107.2382498    over  Ram   3.314496454       log n   513.6602871     bump   491^1
 ratio   108.2539705    over  Ram   3.240575218       log n   519.8728932     bump   499^1
 ratio   109.2731903    over  Ram   3.271085492       log n   526.0934834     bump   503^1
 ratio   110.292897    over  Ram   3.301610344       log n   532.3259314     bump   509^1
 ratio   111.3042884    over  Ram   3.331886276       log n   538.5816814     bump   521^1
 ratio   112.3220256    over  Ram   3.257208542       log n   544.8412629     bump   523^1
 ratio   113.3233319    over  Ram   3.286245266       log n   551.1346822     bump   541^1
 ratio   114.3252422    over  Ram   3.315299503       log n   557.439131     bump   547^1
 ratio   115.3223698    over  Ram   3.344215048       log n   563.7616962     bump   557^1
 ratio   116.320144    over  Ram   3.268343789       log n   570.0949758     bump   563^1
 ratio   117.3185812    over  Ram   3.296397707       log n   576.4388563     bump   569^1
 ratio   118.3229419    over  Ram   3.324618066       log n   582.7862455     bump   571^1
 ratio   119.3279906    over  Ram   3.249339042       log n   589.1440878     bump   577^1
 ratio   120.3285981    over  Ram   3.276585902       log n   595.5191126     bump   587^1
 ratio   121.3299295    over  Ram   3.303852473       log n   601.904307     bump   593^1
 ratio   122.3319989    over  Ram   3.331139143       log n   608.2995686     bump   599^1
 ratio   123.3398218    over  Ram   3.255529759       log n   614.6981635     bump   601^1
 ratio   124.3484052    over  Ram   3.282151114       log n   621.1066923     bump   607^1
 ratio   125.3577623    over  Ram   3.308792893       log n   627.5250572     bump   613^1
 ratio   126.370361    over  Ram   3.335520231       log n   633.9499263     bump   617^1
 ratio   127.3886645    over  Ram   3.259857576       log n   640.3780315     bump   619^1
 ratio   128.4004973    over  Ram   3.285750232       log n   646.8253374     bump   631^1
 ratio   129.4084107    over  Ram   3.311542589       log n   653.2883669     bump   641^1
 ratio   130.4218652    over  Ram   3.337476745       log n   659.7545116     bump   643^1
 ratio   131.4385169    over  Ram   3.261534446       log n   666.2268579     bump   647^1
 ratio   132.4560248    over  Ram   3.286783033       log n   672.708435     bump   653^1
 ratio   133.4743996    over  Ram   3.312053134       log n   679.1991585     bump   659^1
 ratio   134.4982745    over  Ram   3.337459713       log n   685.6929124     bump   661^1
 ratio   135.5161752    over  Ram   3.261385529       log n   692.2046577     bump   673^1
 ratio   135.8203463    over  Ram   3.268705832       log n   694.1505679     bump   7^4
 ratio   136.8436943    over  Ram   3.293334126       log n   700.6682391     bump   677^1
 ratio   137.4137237    over  Ram   3.307052677       log n   704.279157     bump   37^2
 ratio   137.5227394    over  Ram   3.309676293       log n   704.9723042     bump   2^12
 ratio   138.5520797    over  Ram   3.334448801       log n   711.4987991     bump   683^1
 ratio   139.5801067    over  Ram   3.258552335       log n   718.0369389     bump   691^1
 ratio   140.6046611    over  Ram   3.282470958       log n   724.5894468     bump   701^1
 ratio   141.6279895    over  Ram   3.306360962       log n   731.1533023     bump   709^1
 ratio   142.6479948    over  Ram   3.330173386       log n   737.7311637     bump   719^1
 ratio   143.6668556    over  Ram   3.353959091       log n   744.3200902     bump   727^1
 ratio   144.6866876    over  Ram   3.277153174       log n   750.9172359     bump   733^1
 ratio   145.7074983    over  Ram   3.300274535       log n   757.5225338     bump   739^1
 ratio   146.7313577    over  Ram   3.323464947       log n   764.1332298     bump   743^1
 ratio   147.754163    over  Ram   3.346631486       log n   770.7546355     bump   751^1
 ratio   148.0025434    over  Ram   3.352257301       log n   772.3640734     bump   5^5
 ratio   149.0280708    over  Ram   3.275506404       log n   778.9934366     bump   757^1
 ratio   149.4258815    over  Ram   3.284249934       log n   781.558386     bump   13^3
 ratio   150.457187    over  Ram   3.306917125       log n   788.1930194     bump   761^1
 ratio   151.4874976    over  Ram   3.32956245       log n   794.8381103     bump   769^1
 ratio   152.5208351    over  Ram   3.352274302       log n   801.4883894     bump   773^1
 ratio   153.5473095    over  Ram   3.275430973       log n   808.1566176     bump   787^1
 ratio   154.5709524    over  Ram   3.297267055       log n   814.8374723     bump   797^1
 ratio   155.5899343    over  Ram   3.319003711       log n   821.5332712     bump   809^1
 ratio   156.613736    over  Ram   3.340843181       log n   828.2315393     bump   811^1
 ratio   157.6348459    over  Ram   3.264122817       log n   834.9420624     bump   821^1
 ratio   158.6607396    over  Ram   3.285365855       log n   841.6550186     bump   823^1
 ratio   159.2299653    over  Ram   3.297152732       log n   845.3685906     bump   41^2
 ratio   160.2624786    over  Ram   3.318532842       log n   852.0863953     bump   827^1
 ratio   161.2998063    over  Ram   3.340012641       log n   858.8066155     bump   829^1
 ratio   162.3345013    over  Ram   3.361437928       log n   865.5388262     bump   839^1
 ratio   163.3629889    over  Ram   3.284177807       log n   872.2875857     bump   853^1
 ratio   164.3943674    over  Ram   3.304912187       log n   879.0410237     bump   857^1
 ratio   165.4304444    over  Ram   3.325741025       log n   885.7967926     bump   859^1
 ratio   166.4694248    over  Ram   3.34662823       log n   892.5572073     bump   863^1
 ratio   167.5023879    over  Ram   3.269806211       log n   899.3337143     bump   877^1
 ratio   168.5382193    over  Ram   3.290026627       log n   906.1147719     bump   881^1
 ratio   169.5786852    over  Ram   3.310337514       log n   912.8980971     bump   883^1
 ratio   170.6220317    over  Ram   3.330704631       log n   919.6859421     bump   887^1
 ratio   171.1931289    over  Ram   3.341852992       log n   923.4471422     bump   43^2
 ratio   172.2289407    over  Ram   3.362073026       log n   930.2572846     bump   907^1
 ratio   173.2675862    over  Ram   3.284840511       log n   937.0718275     bump   911^1
 ratio   174.3056659    over  Ram   3.304520627       log n   943.8951137     bump   919^1
 ratio   175.3415227    over  Ram   3.324158601       log n   950.7292224     bump   929^1
 ratio   176.3768557    over  Ram   3.343786646       log n   957.5719057     bump   937^1
 ratio   177.4149801    over  Ram   3.363467609       log n   964.4188488     bump   941^1
 ratio   178.4542487    over  Ram   3.286142674       log n   971.2721479     bump   947^1
 ratio   179.4946651    over  Ram   3.305301405       log n   978.1317628     bump   953^1
 ratio   180.5297637    over  Ram   3.324362209       log n   985.0059613     bump   967^1
 ratio   181.5676132    over  Ram   3.343473671       log n   991.8842878     bump   971^1
 ratio   182.6066178    over  Ram   3.362606403       log n   998.7687744     bump   977^1
 ratio   183.6467807    over  Ram   3.285267457       log n   1005.659384     bump   983^1
 ratio   184.6865287    over  Ram   3.303867566       log n   1012.558098     bump   991^1
 ratio   185.7274403    over  Ram   3.322488492       log n   1019.462849     bump   997^1
 ratio   186.7648676    over  Ram   3.341047087       log n   1026.379564     bump   1009^1
 ratio   187.8049988    over  Ram   3.359654051       log n   1033.300235     bump   1013^1
 ratio   188.8463003    over  Ram   3.282372532       log n   1040.226812     bump   1019^1
 ratio   189.8918367    over  Ram   3.300545195       log n   1047.15535     bump   1021^1
 ratio   190.9355046    over  Ram   3.318685379       log n   1054.093635     bump   1031^1
 ratio   191.9833843    over  Ram   3.336898771       log n   1061.033857     bump   1033^1
 ratio   193.0324483    over  Ram   3.355132747       log n   1067.979871     bump   1039^1
 ratio   194.0796943    over  Ram   3.278040755       log n   1074.935464     bump   1049^1
 ratio   195.1311187    over  Ram   3.295799501       log n   1081.892961     bump   1051^1
 ratio   196.1807578    over  Ram   3.313528093       log n   1088.859928     bump   1061^1
 ratio   197.2345536    over  Ram   3.331326893       log n   1095.828779     bump   1063^1
 ratio   198.289547    over  Ram   3.349145919       log n   1102.803258     bump   1069^1
 ratio   198.8724667    over  Ram   3.358991537       log n   1106.653405     bump   47^2
 ratio   199.9229823    over  Ram   3.281810856       log n   1113.644582     bump   1087^1
 ratio   200.9761418    over  Ram   3.299098865       log n   1120.639432     bump   1091^1
 ratio   202.0333959    over  Ram   3.316454089       log n   1127.636114     bump   1093^1
 ratio   203.093304    over  Ram   3.333852877       log n   1134.636448     bump   1097^1
 ratio   204.1544227    over  Ram   3.35127154       log n   1141.642237     bump   1103^1
 ratio   205.2167544    over  Ram   3.368710113       log n   1148.653451     bump   1109^1
 ratio   206.2788728    over  Ram   3.291415684       log n   1155.671853     bump   1117^1
 ratio   207.3422073    over  Ram   3.308382405       log n   1162.695612     bump   1123^1
 ratio   208.4067603    over  Ram   3.325368567       log n   1169.724699     bump   1129^1
 ratio   209.4614029    over  Ram   3.342196597       log n   1176.773086     bump   1151^1
 ratio   210.5200032    over  Ram   3.359087778       log n   1183.823208     bump   1153^1
 ratio   211.577085    over  Ram   3.375954729       log n   1190.881966     bump   1163^1
 ratio   212.6340265    over  Ram   3.298354947       log n   1197.94758     bump   1171^1
 ratio   212.7979734    over  Ram   3.300898072       log n   1199.046192     bump   3^8
 ratio   213.8542558    over  Ram   3.317283006       log n   1206.120309     bump   1181^1
 ratio   214.9117545    over  Ram   3.333686807       log n   1213.199493     bump   1187^1
 ratio   215.9704714    over  Ram   3.350109503       log n   1220.28372     bump   1193^1
 ratio   217.0290842    over  Ram   3.366530584       log n   1227.37463     bump   1201^1
 ratio   218.0849831    over  Ram   3.289163364       log n   1234.475481     bump   1213^1
 ratio   219.1434026    over  Ram   3.305126474       log n   1241.579626     bump   1217^1
 ratio   219.2466955    over  Ram   3.30668434       log n   1242.272773     bump   2^13
 ratio   220.3068355    over  Ram   3.322673399       log n   1249.381835     bump   1223^1
 ratio   221.3681987    over  Ram   3.338680907       log n   1256.495791     bump   1229^1
 ratio   222.4333755    over  Ram   3.354745931       log n   1263.611373     bump   1231^1
 ratio   223.4997818    over  Ram   3.370829498       log n   1270.731817     bump   1237^1
 ratio   224.5635702    over  Ram   3.29345261       log n   1277.861916     bump   1249^1
 ratio   225.6260484    over  Ram   3.30903493       log n   1284.999989     bump   1259^1
 ratio   226.6822481    over  Ram   3.324525172       log n   1292.152258     bump   1277^1
 ratio   227.7421474    over  Ram   3.34006967       log n   1299.306092     bump   1279^1
 ratio   228.8045116    over  Ram   3.355650319       log n   1306.463048     bump   1283^1
 ratio   229.8681032    over  Ram   3.371248969       log n   1313.62467     bump   1289^1
 ratio   230.9353971    over  Ram   3.293907657       log n   1320.787842     bump   1291^1
 ratio   232.0039242    over  Ram   3.309148411       log n   1327.955652     bump   1297^1
 ratio   233.074919    over  Ram   3.324424362       log n   1335.12654     bump   1301^1
 ratio   234.1496189    over  Ram   3.339753162       log n   1342.298965     bump   1303^1
 ratio   235.2267951    over  Ram   3.355117282       log n   1349.474454     bump   1307^1
 ratio   236.3015346    over  Ram   3.370446645       log n   1356.659084     bump   1319^1
 ratio   237.3799583    over  Ram   3.293283751       log n   1363.845228     bump   1321^1
 ratio   238.4596279    over  Ram   3.308262515       log n   1371.035904     bump   1327^1
 ratio   239.0477073    over  Ram   3.316421218       log n   1375.006196     bump   53^2
 ratio   240.114527    over  Ram   3.331221707       log n   1382.222171     bump   1361^1
 ratio   241.1825781    over  Ram   3.346039283       log n   1389.442545     bump   1367^1
 ratio   242.251862    over  Ram   3.360873961       log n   1396.667298     bump   1373^1
 ratio   243.3212169    over  Ram   3.375709625       log n   1403.897861     bump   1381^1
 ratio   244.3849109    over  Ram   3.298208543       log n   1411.141374     bump   1399^1
 ratio   245.4475631    over  Ram   3.312550053       log n   1418.39201     bump   1409^1
 ratio   246.5069511    over  Ram   3.326847509       log n   1425.652532     bump   1423^1
 ratio   247.568674    over  Ram   3.341176477       log n   1432.915862     bump   1427^1
 ratio   248.6338503    over  Ram   3.355552052       log n   1440.180592     bump   1429^1
 ratio   249.7013693    over  Ram   3.369959244       log n   1447.448117     bump   1433^1
 ratio   250.7701174    over  Ram   3.292696017       log n   1454.719821     bump   1439^1
 ratio   251.8389861    over  Ram   3.306730623       log n   1461.997069     bump   1447^1
 ratio   252.9101907    over  Ram   3.320795899       log n   1469.277077     bump   1451^1
 ratio   253.9848409    over  Ram   3.334906418       log n   1476.558463     bump   1453^1
 ratio   255.060727    over  Ram   3.349033165       log n   1483.843969     bump   1459^1
 ratio   256.1345535    over  Ram   3.363132868       log n   1491.137667     bump   1471^1
 ratio   257.2074353    over  Ram   3.377220167       log n   1498.43814     bump   1481^1
 ratio   258.2837212    over  Ram   3.299876046       log n   1505.739962     bump   1483^1
 ratio   259.3623296    over  Ram   3.313656527       log n   1513.044478     bump   1487^1
 ratio   260.4443511    over  Ram   3.327480615       log n   1520.350338     bump   1489^1
 ratio   261.5287026    over  Ram   3.341334471       log n   1527.658881     bump   1493^1
 ratio   262.6142983    over  Ram   3.355204224       log n   1534.971435     bump   1499^1
 ratio   263.6979009    over  Ram   3.369048512       log n   1542.291961     bump   1511^1
 ratio   264.7795384    over  Ram   3.382867694       log n   1549.620399     bump   1523^1
 ratio   265.8613535    over  Ram   3.305462762       log n   1556.954075     bump   1531^1
 ratio   266.9412466    over  Ram   3.318889108       log n   1564.295559     bump   1543^1
 ratio   268.0223746    over  Ram   3.332330807       log n   1571.640924     bump   1549^1
 ratio   269.1057836    over  Ram   3.345800867       log n   1578.988868     bump   1553^1
 ratio   270.1904307    over  Ram   3.359286319       log n   1586.340668     bump   1559^1
 ratio   271.275277    over  Ram   3.372774248       log n   1593.697586     bump   1567^1
 ratio   272.3623985    over  Ram   3.295729417       log n   1601.057054     bump   1571^1
 ratio   273.4497264    over  Ram   3.308886662       log n   1608.421601     bump   1579^1
 ratio   274.5393257    over  Ram   3.322071391       log n   1615.788678     bump   1583^1
 ratio   275.6260663    over  Ram   3.335221528       log n   1623.16456     bump   1597^1
 ratio   276.7150635    over  Ram   3.348398972       log n   1630.542943     bump   1601^1
 ratio   277.8053005    over  Ram   3.361591417       log n   1637.925068     bump   1607^1
 ratio   278.8988123    over  Ram   3.37482349       log n   1645.308436     bump   1609^1
 ratio   279.9945861    over  Ram   3.297853938       log n   1652.694287     bump   1613^1
 ratio   280.4154458    over  Ram   3.302810941       log n   1655.5275     bump   17^3
 ratio   281.5141146    over  Ram   3.315751367       log n   1662.917064     bump   1619^1
 ratio   282.6160672    over  Ram   3.328730471       log n   1670.307863     bump   1621^1
 ratio   283.7192721    over  Ram   3.341724324       log n   1677.702356     bump   1627^1
 ratio   284.8217054    over  Ram   3.35470909       log n   1685.102977     bump   1637^1
 ratio   285.9183887    over  Ram   3.367626129       log n   1692.515741     bump   1657^1
 ratio   287.0163142    over  Ram   3.380557801       log n   1699.932119     bump   1663^1
 ratio   287.6212267    over  Ram   3.387682628       log n   1704.009656     bump   59^2
```