# About colossally abundant numbers - reference request

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, mathematical-software

This post contains three related questions:

1. In the OEIS sequence 073751 ( https://oeis.org/A073751/ ) there is a short Mathematica program that is said to produce the prime factors of successive [colossally abundant numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossally_abundant_number). Is there a proof of this anywhere, or would anybody know how to prove this?
2. In the same site, it is said that a conjecture of Alaoglu and Erdös - namely, that the ratio of two successive colossally abundant numbers is a prime - has been checked up to the 10^7-th colossally abundant number. Would anybody know who has done this and where can one read about it.
3. Would the program on the OEIS site be able to check the Alaoglu and Erdös conjecture with some modification (not considering performance issues), and if so, how could this be done?

Comment: I put the two formulas needed at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79927/which-n-maximize-gn-frac-sigmann-log-log-n/79987#79987  My C++  program is this: given an upper bound on  $p^k.$   Produce a file of $ ( \delta, p, k)$  and sort by decreasing $\delta.$  As long as two consecutive $\delta$   values are visibly distinct, the ratio of consecutive CA numbers is prime. Finally, read through the file,  for each line  of the final output, multiply the number by $p$  so that the new CA number $n$ has  $v_p(n) = k.$  That's about it.

Comment: the analogous conjecture for Superior Highly Composite numbers is discussed in http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/hcnrevisited.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you. What you have is slightly different. The program in the OEIS website calculates, when computing the $n$-th prime factor that gives rise to the $n$-th CA number, the number $\frac{\log \left(\frac{p^{k+2}-1}{p^{k+1}-1}\right)}{\log (p)}-1$ for all the prime factors and their current powers in the $n-1$-th CA number, and for the smallest prime not a factor of that CA num. with power 0. And it chooses as the $n$-th factor that prime for which the computed number is largest - continued in the next comment -

Comment: If the A&E conjecture is true, this is an extremely efficient way to calculate these factors and the corresponding CA numbers (if you program it right). So my question was, first, whether this method is  really calculating these factors in order as claimed, secondly, whether the A&E conjecture has really been checked up to 10^7 (or higher as it were), and thirdly, if the A&E conjecture were false, whether this program can be used to check that somehow.

Comment: In the question you refer to, Joro claims that Briggs made calculations up to 10^11 ... I was unable to find any paper concerning these matters.

Comment: I don't have mathematica. I recommend you run that to find the first 20 primes in the order of that OEIS page.   In my posted answer below, I put the raw data from my initial program, then the desired version in reverse sort. Last I put the beginning from the file by Noe.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the initial part of my programs. The program takes primes   and exponents and produces the correct decimal $\delta$ value. Then I tell it to sort that in reverse.

For comparison, run the Mathematica thing and see if it also correctly finds the prime sequence at the OEIS page.

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Colossally_Abundant_construct_deltas  0.01
0.5849625007211564           2           1
0.2223924213364479           2           2
0.0995356735509147           2           3
0.0473057147783566           2           4
0.0230836131130409           2           5
0.0114047632722493           2           6
0.2618595071429147           3           1
0.0728580123298782           3           2
0.0230452619595065           3           3
0.1132827525593782           5           1
0.0203734624179445           5           2
0.0686215613240664           7           1
0.0362865626271021          11           1
0.0288925673866187          13           1
0.0201744121952064          17           1
0.0174203964661791          19           1
0.0135734947947221          23           1
0.0100678863359082          29           1
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ 
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ 
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Colossally_Abundant_construct_deltas  0.01  | sort -n -r
0.5849625007211564           2           1
0.2618595071429147           3           1
0.2223924213364479           2           2
0.1132827525593782           5           1
0.0995356735509147           2           3
0.0728580123298782           3           2
0.0686215613240664           7           1
0.0473057147783566           2           4
0.0362865626271021          11           1
0.0288925673866187          13           1
0.0230836131130409           2           5
0.0230452619595065           3           3
0.0203734624179445           5           2
0.0201744121952064          17           1
0.0174203964661791          19           1
0.0135734947947221          23           1
0.0114047632722493           2           6
0.0100678863359082          29           1
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

FROM:
https://oeis.org/A073751/b073751.txt

```
1 2
2 3
3 2
4 5
5 2
6 3
7 7
8 2
9 11
10 13
11 2
12 3
13 5
14 17
15 19
16 23
17 2
18 29
19 31
20 7
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Comment: Thank you. Yes, in fact I have my own Mathematica version of the program, I can compute the factors up to 10^8 in 2 hours with 30 digit precision (you absolutely need this). I also have a Fortran version with 128 bit arithmetic which is much much faster (I am still tweaking it). So indeed, these programs based on the site one seem to work. But is there proof of it? And, if the AE conjecture does not hold, what would these programs churn: two delta numbers that are the same?

Comment: I want to make these programs public, if it makes sense.

Comment: @EGME  yes, two identical delta numbers. For the analogous SHC   numbers, Siegel was able to prove that no three primes produce the same delta, but the case of just two primes is still unknown.

Comment: If that is the case, then the programs can be used to check the AE conjecture, and I know how to do it. What I would like to see more formally and have not found anywhere is precisely that, that two primes with their powers will produce the same delta if the AE conjecture is false ... it is at least one step removed from what is in the A&E paper ... but I believe you.  So ok, I will think of a good place to put this in. I will try to put together some formally convincing note about this, with some help.  Thanks!! indeed.

Comment: @EGME   suggest you answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349588/how-would-i-find-a-number-where-sum-d-mid-nd-100n  with the first CA   number $n$   with $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}  \geq 100$

Comment: I would if I find it ... I will see how big that is for the 10^8-th one, probably not big enough. It is hard to go beyond, because you need to increase the digit precision, and it becomes too slow, unless you can access a supercomputer (which has Mathematica - 128 bit arithmetic will not be enough to do, say, 10^9, and arbitrary precision libraries are not that faster than what Mathematica has)

Comment: My estimate is that such a number will appear around the 10^20-th, or 10^21-th CA number ... it is a simply huge number, beyond my computational resources; I will try to produce a better estimate later.